# Compare 2 table rows with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to compare 2 rows in a database using Laravel Eloquent Models.

I have a model called `History` and this runs routinely every hour and inserts newly found data into the table `history`.

Sometimes the data on 2 rows could be exactly the same and I want to be able to determine in the model whether or not the 2 rows are identical or they have differences.

The differences can literally be just 1 column but I need to know the difference so I know whether or not to send an email to the client.

I know I can do it by selecting the latest and the row before and compare all of the columns individually but I didn't really want to have to do this so I didn't know if there was a different way in order to do this or whether I would have to do this manually and check each column.

I have also seen a method called `isDirty`.

I don't know if it would be possible to select the latest and then pass in the previous rows data?

Columns could be added in the future which is why I want to automate it.

This is the current method / model that I have:

```php
class History extends Model
{
    public function hasIndescrepencies()
    {
       $current = $this->query()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();
        $previous = $this->query()->where('id', '<', $current->id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you only want to do it on one model comparing the `current` and `previous` rows in that table, here's how I would solve this:

```
<?php

class History extends Model
{
    public function hasIndescrepencies(): bool
    {
        $current = $this->query()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->first();
        $previous = null;
        if ($current) {
            $previous = $this->query()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->where('id', '!=', $current->id)->first();
        }

        if ($current && $previous) {

            $current = $current->toArray();
            $previous = $previous->toArray();

            $ignoreColumns = array_flip(['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);

            $currentDataKeys = array_filter(array_keys($current), function($key) use($ignoreColumns) {
                return !array_key_exists($key, $ignoreColumns);
            });

            $currentData = [];
            foreach ($currentDataKeys as $currentDataKey) {
                $currentData[$currentDataKey] = $current[$currentDataKey];
            }

            $previousDataKeys = array_filter(array_keys($previous), function($key) use($ignoreColumns) {
                return !array_key_exists($key, $ignoreColumns);
            });

            $previousData = [];
            foreach ($previousDataKeys as $previousDataKey) {
                $previousData[$previousDataKey] = $previous[$previousDataKey];
            }

            return !empty(array_diff($currentData, $previousData))

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. You load the most recent updated row and then previous row is selected the same way as current, while excluding the current row's id.
2. If the first row and second row exist, then you proceed to do the check. it is possible for this table to start with just one row or no rows at all.
3. Then get a key => value pair of values for both current and previous row (excluding certain columns like id, created_at & updated_at - because these will be different even though the underlying row data might not have changed)
4. Then compare the array diff and see if something exists

---

Here's how I confirmed it works using pure php array:

```
$current = [
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'bob',
    'age' => 21,
    'created_at' => '2019-01-01 00:00:00',
    'updated_at' => '2019-01-02 00:00:00',
];

$previous = [
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'bob',
    'age' => 20,
    'created_at' => '2019-01-03 00:00:00',
    'updated_at' => '2019-01-04 00:00:00',
];

$ignoreColumns = array_flip(['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);

$currentDataKeys = array_filter(array_keys($current), function($key) use($ignoreColumns) {
    return !array_key_exists($key, $ignoreColumns);
});

$currentData = [];
foreach ($currentDataKeys as $currentDataKey) {
    $currentData[$currentDataKey] = $current[$currentDataKey];
}

$previousDataKeys = array_filter(array_keys($previous), function($key) use($ignoreColumns) {
    return !array_key_exists($key, $ignoreColumns);
});

$previousData = [];
foreach ($previousDataKeys as $previousDataKey) {
    $previousData[$previousDataKey] = $previous[$previousDataKey];
}

var_dump(array_diff($currentData, $previousData));
```

The result of var_dump should look something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["age"]=>
  int(21)
}
```

Which is correct, as the only thing that is different from current and previous was the age key's value.

Hope this helps.